# Where does it converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, poisson-distribution

Where does $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda}}{\sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda}}$
converges? I got the following, but I don't know how to continue.
I'm confused whether it is $0$ or $1?$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda}}{\sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda}}{1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda}-\frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-\lambda}}{1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda}}=$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}1-\frac{\frac{\lambda^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-\lambda}}{1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda}}=...
$$

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on $\lambda$? If not someone can show that IF the limit exists it depends on $\lambda$

Comment: Just the basics: λ>0...  I think in the numerator and in the denominator there are the tail distribution of the Poisson distribution, so λ>0... (I hope its english name is tail distribution, but I'm not sure...however I know we call some distribution fat tailed distribution (Cauchy for example), and by fat tail they think of it...so I'm not far from its original english name :DD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{k \geq n}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}\sim_{+\infty} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$ and so the limit will be $0$